# How to change an element in matrix, based on equality of other elements?

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, row

I have following problem. I can solve it without any real troubles using 2 for cycles. Knowing it is not really a Mathematica friendly approach, can you give me suggestions of a nice Mathematica code?
I have two arrays of random numbers and where these numbers are equal to each other, I have to add +1 to original values of these elements and make a final matrix: matrix1.

```
capacityofLines = {55, 63, 87, 45, 61, 45, 69, 87};

randomExample = {55, 63, 87, 45, 20, -30, 69, 120};

equalszero = capacityofLines - randomExample;

equals = Position[equalszero, _?(# == 0 &)] // Flatten
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 7}

```
matrix1 = Table[capacityofLines, Length[equals]];

matrix2 = Table[capacityofLines, Length[equals]];
matrix3 = Table[x, Length[equals]];


For[i = 1, i <= Length[equals], i++, 
 matrix3[[i]] = capacityofLines[[equals[[i]]]] + 1]


For[i = 1, i <= Length[equals], i++, 
  matrix1[[i, equals[[i]]]] = matrix3[[i]]]

matrix1 // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: could you post `capacityofLines`?

Comment: Working backwards, from `equalszero`, `capacityofLines` must be `{55, 63, 87, 45, ??, 69, ??}`. I guess the actual values don't matter as long as they are different from the corresponding values in `randomExample`.

Comment: In fact, when one edits OP's code, the definition `capacityofLines`is here. It seems that the OP has difficulties with the editor.

Comment: OP's question corrected. Hope my corrections are OK.

Answer (score 3):

```
capacityofLines = {55, 63, 87, 45, 61, 45, 69, 87};

randomExample = {55, 63, 87, 45, 20, -30, 69, 120};

equalszero = capacityofLines - randomExample;

equals = Position[equalszero, _?(# == 0 &)] // Flatten
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 7}
> ```

Given `capacityofLines` and `equals` you can get your `matrix1` in a single step as follows:

```
matrix1 = MapAt[# + 1 &, Table[capacityofLines, Length[equals]], 
   Transpose[{Range@Length@equals, equals}]];


matrix1 // TableForm
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Alternatively,

```
sa = SparseArray[Transpose[{Range@Length@equals, equals}] -> 1, 
   Length /@ {equals, capacityofLines}];

matrix1b = Table[capacityofLines, Length[equals]] + sa;

matrix1b == matrix1
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Taking `capacityOfLines` and `randomExample` as input, we can do

```
matrix1c = Module[{pos = MapIndexed[Join[#2, #] &, 
   SparseArray[1 - Unitize[capacityofLines - randomExample]]["NonzeroPositions"]]}, 
   MapAt[# + 1 &, Table[capacityofLines, Length@pos], pos]];

matrix1c == matrix1
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Comment: NIce. Thank zou for the answer